# Como puedo hacer un conteo con una lista de agentes repetidos

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente: tengo una lista de registro de agentes lo cuales quiero saber cuantos registros tiene cada agente hacer un conteo por cada nombre y a la ves quiero que me liste el Conteo y el nombre de ese agente que tiene ese conteo como resultado pero no quiero que me duplique el Nombre del agente, lo estoy intentando hacer con `ajax` y `C#` `MVC5`

Algo como esto pero en una tabla el agente en la base datos esta repetido pero no quiero que se visualice repetido, si no que me cuente cuanta veces esta repetido..

> 1. Agente1 = 10 Repetido
> 2. Agente2 = 16 Repetido
> 3. Agente3 = 26 Repetido

```
public ActionResult ObtenerSupervisor()
{
   var Supervisores = db.Ausencias.Select(p => p.Supervisor).ToList();

   foreach (var item in Supervisores)
   {
      var conteo = db.Ausencias.Where(a => a.Supervisor == item).Count();
      return View(conteo);
   }

   //db.Ausencias.Select(p => p.Supervisor).ToList().Distinct();
   return Json(Supervisores.Distinct(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Esto es mi script

```
$("#btninicio").click(function () {
   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "/Datos/ObtenerSupervisor",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: "",
      success: function (resultado) {
         $.each(resultado, function (i, item) {
            var row = "<tr>" + "<td>" + item + "</td>" "</tr>";

         $("#tabla>tbody").append(row);
      });

//for (var i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++) {
//    $("#tabla>tbody").append(resultado["Supervisores"]);
//}
},
     error: function (xhr, status) {
        alert('Error de conexion');
     },
});
})
```

Comment: Agrega la estructura de tus tablas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que usar el `group by` de `linq`, algo como esto

```
public ActionResult ObtenerSupervisor()
{
   var query = (from ausencia in db.Ausencias
                group ausencia by ausencia.Supervisor into g
                select new {
                   Supervisor = g.Key,
                   conteo = g.Count();
                }).ToList();                

   return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

[Agrupar los resultados de consultas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results)

Comment: Muchas Gracias me funciono perfectamente.